# Seeding the random generator for tests

Tags: python, django, random, random-seed, factory-boy

I made it work using `factory-boy`'s `get_random_state`/`set_random_state`, although it wasn't easy. And the biggest downside is that the values are big. So the thing that comes to mind is to write it to a file. But then if I accidentally run the tests not telling it to seed from the file, the value is lost. Now that I think about it, I can display the value too (think `tee`). But still I'd like to reduce it to 4-5 digits.

My idea is as follows. Normally when you run tests it somewhere says, "seed: 4215." Then to reproduce the same result I've got to do `SEED=4215 ./manage.py test` or something.

I did some experiments with `factory-boy`, but then I realized that I can't achieve this even with the `random` module itself. I tried different ideas. All of them failed so far. The simplest is this:

```py
import random
import os
if os.getenv('A'):
    random.seed(os.getenv('A'))
else:
    seed = random.randint(0, 1000)
    random.seed(seed)
    print('seed: {}'.format(seed))
print(random.random())
print(random.random())
```

```
/app $ A= python a.py
seed: 62
0.9279915658776743
0.17302689004804395

/app $ A=62 python a.py
0.461603098412836
0.7402019819205794
```

Why do the results differ? And how to make them equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your types are different:

```py
if os.getenv('A'):
    random.seed(os.getenv('A'))
else:
    seed = random.randint(0, 1000)
    random.seed(seed)
    print('seed: {}'.format(seed))
```

In the first case, you have a `str` and in the second an `int`. You can fix this by casting an `int` in the first case:

`random.seed(int(os.getenv("A")))`

I'm also not entirely following your need to seed `random` directly; I think with Factory Boy you can use `factory.random.reseed_random` ([source](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#reproducible-random-values)).

Comment: Indeed, a silly mistake. As for `reseed_random()`, that was me trying to make it work with the `random` module alone. For tests I'm going to use `reseed_random()`. Actually I have another related question. Should I not ask it here?.. Where do I put this code? With Django you can have multiple apps, so putting it in one of them (`app1/tests.py`) doesn't seem right (affects others), although should work.

Comment: For your specific need, I believe the recommended solution is to use Django's extension points: create a subclass of `django.test.runner.DiscoverTestRunner`, where you expand `setup_test_environment()` to include your seeding code; then point the `TEST_RUNNER` setting to that class. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner for details :)